# Java Strace gork pattern in logstash filter

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

i have following error log . I need to right the gork pattern for it . My pattern is only able to read first line . could anyone help me to read the other line and store the line in extraline field .
Here the expression which i am currently on

```
\[%{NOTSPACE:thread}\] \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\] (?<timestamp>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}) (?<logger>[A-Za-z0-9$_.]+):%{NOTSPACE:method}\(\):%{NONNEGINT:line} - %{GREEDYDATA:message}$
```

Log which needs to be parsed

```
[pool-4-thread-1] [ERROR] 2019-06-19 12:56:14,827 com.chaipoint.boxc.dao.OrderDispenseDataDao:updateOrderStatusOnDispenseScheduler():218 - Error while updating status in scheduler
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:627)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:906)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:930)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:313)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:318)
    at com.chaipoint.boxc.dao.OrderDispenseDataDao.updateOrderStatusOnDispenseScheduler(OrderDispenseDataDao.java:216)
    at com.chaipoint.boxc.dao.OrderDispenseDataDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e49056b7.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
```

Output expected is

```
method : updateOrderStatusOnDispenseScheduler
timestamp : 2019-06-19·12:56:14,827
logger : com.chaipoint.boxc.dao.OrderDispenseDataDao
line : 218
thread : pool-4-thread-1
message : Error·while·updating·status·in·scheduler
loglevel : ERROR
extra line : org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:627)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:906)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:930)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:313)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:318)
    at com.chaipoint.boxc.dao.OrderDispenseDataDao.updateOrderStatusOnDispenseScheduler(OrderDispenseDataDao.java:216)
    at com.chaipoint.boxc.dao.OrderDispenseDataDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e49056b7.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My pattern is only able to read first line

To read multiple lines use: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html

> For example, Java stack traces are multiline and usually have the message starting at the far-left, with each subsequent line indented. Do this:

```
input {
  stdin {
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^\s"
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}
```